# refresh token rotation with express

Tags: express, refresh-token

I followed a tutorial for that, here is the repository : https://github.com/gitdagray/refresh_token_rotation/tree/a55fe1057f50e7b5a28c5a7db05f1cdbb01c2ad2/controllers

It works great, but I need to understand a little thing.

At the login, if there is no cookie with the value of the current refresh token, the tutorial updates the database by keeping the old refresh tokens and adding the one that has just been created at login.

Thus, for each manual deletion of cookies, another refresh token is added to database. (5 manual deletion before login = 5 refresh tokens in database.

```
let newRefreshTokenArray = !cookies?.jwt
  ? foundUser.refresh.tokens
  : foundUser.refresh.tokens.filter((rt) => rt !== cookies.jwt);
```

... And after that :

```
foundUser.refresh.tokens = [...newRefreshTokenArray, newRefreshToken];
```

What I need to understand is, do you think there is a reason to stock all of them ?

The tutorial is not clear about that, and I need to understand this point.

Thanks by advance !!